# Merged tags failing using terragrunt and terraform

Tags: terraform, terragrunt, hcl

I have the following file structure:

```
.
├── terragrunt.hcl
└── root.hcl /
    └── env.hcl /
        └── workload.hcl/
            └── terragrunt.hcl
```

within each config (hcl file), there are tags such as:

**root**

```
locals {  
  tags = {   
    root= "test"
  } 
}
```

**env**

```
locals {  
  tags = {  
    env = "test"
  }
}
```

**workload**

```
locals {  
  tags = {   
    workload = "test"
  } 
}
```

These tags are merged in the child terragrunt.hcl using the following.

```
locals {
  root_vars   = (read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("root.hcl"))).locals
  env_vars      = (read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl"))).locals
  workload_vars = (read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("workload.hcl"))).locals
  merged_tags = merge(local.root_vars.tags, local.env_vars.tags, local.workload_vars.tags)
}
inputs = {
  tags = local.merged_tags
}
```

The subsequent terragrunt plans all fail with the following error.

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 46, in resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm":
│   46:   tags = var.tags
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.tags is "{\"root\":\"test\",\"env\":\"test\",\"workload\":\"test\"}"
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": map of string required.
```

Anyone know what i am doing wrong here?

terragrunt plan = expected addition of tags to resources

Comment: You can maybe try `jsondecode(var.tags)` but not sure if that's the reason.

Comment: I thought that too, doesn't seem to work though, thanks for the assist mind.

Comment: What's the definition for the `tags` variable? Did you define it as a map of strings?

Comment: I did, i am not sure how I've fixed this, I did have the tags input listed twice which could have been the issue. However, the above seems to now work...
I've also updated my tf and terragrunt versions